# check the element in the array and if it doesn't exist out data into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, select

The problem is in the title:
I have to find out whether the element exists or not in the array and if it doesn't put the data into database.

Here is the code:

```
$day = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$logins_array = array();

$logins=mysql_query("SELECT login FROM users");

while($login=mysql_fetch_array($logins))
{
    $logins_array[]=$login;
}

if(!(in_array('"'.$_POST['login'].'"',$logins_array)))
{
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO users(login,password,email,reg_data) VALUES ("'.$_POST['login'].'","'.$_POST['password'].'","'.$_POST['email'].'","'.$day.'")');
}
```

this code works but the data always is insert into database.

how can I do it correctly?

Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching it wrong way then assigning a whole array instead of the element you want to assign. It should be like this

```
while($login=mysql_fetch_assoc($logins))
{
    $logins_array[]=$login["login"];    //add only the relevant value, not the whole array.
}
```

And in_array should look like

```
if(!(in_array($_POST['login'],$logins_array)))      // without those extra quotes
```

[Consider being more protective](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) of your database though, this code is very vulnerable with that `INSERT`

Comment: it doesn't work( (about the database: I check it out on the sql injection, thank you))

Comment: Also update your `in_array` statement like the one I just added. Those quotes are useless there.